# Why in C++ do static_cast<unsigned> of negative numbers differ if the number is constant or not

Tags: c++, casting

What's the C++ rules that means **equal** is *false*?. Given:

```
float f {-1.0};
bool equal = (static_cast<unsigned>(f) == static_cast<unsigned>(-1.0));
```

E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/fcmx2P

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
          float   f {-1.0};
    const float  cf {-1.0};

    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << " f" << "=" << static_cast<unsigned>(f) << '\n';
    std::cout << "cf" << "=" << static_cast<unsigned>(cf) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
 f=ffffffff
cf=0
```

Comment: Have an upvote: you've been caught by an oft-forgotten rule about undefined behaviour!

Comment: What results do you expect converting a negative float to an unsigned?

Comment: @Amadeus probably the usual wrap around we get when converting negative integer.  I had to check that it was UB because that surprised me.

Comment: @Amadeus, it was more a case of understanding the difference. I fixed a typo bug a few weeks ago... a const-float was explicitly cast to unsigned (the bug), and implicitly back to signed (as a signed function parameter). I later pondered why the original bug was causing a zero value in the function. Testing suggests it was because the float was const. A non-const float that was explicitly-cast to unsigned and then implicitly cast back to signed didn't result in the same bahaviour - the twice-cast non-const had the *original* and expected value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is *undefined*: the C++ standard does not define the conversion of a negative *floating point type* to an `unsigned` type.

(Note the familiar wrap-around behaviour only applies to negative *integral* types.)

So therefore there's little point in attempting to explain your program output.

Comment: Is it defined if I'd convert float->int->unsigned instead?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Only if the `float` is within the range of an `int`.

Comment: I accept that UB is the correct answer, and so should be the end of it... but given that...What's the likely compiler-writer answer that explains why all the compilers on Compiler Explorer (clang/gcc/djgpp) produce the equivalent (UB) output?

Comment: @GreyMattR If the compiler can prove that the value is guaranteed to be negative at the time of the cast, then it can leave the result of the cast uninitialized, or set it to zero, or whatever else it wants to do. If the compiler cannot prove that, it has to generate code to perform the cast. For such purposes, it can reuse the code to cast to signed integer type (the result will only be "wrong" if the cast is UB, which means it's not actually wrong). With more aggressive optimization, the cast will not be emitted in the non-const case either.